# passing image from collectionViewCell which is located tableviewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I ask for help with determining the right approach

when I click on the picture I need to pass text and her to new VC, but the problem is that the project has a great depth struct

the cell lies in the `collectionView`, which is in the `tableViewCell`

How do I properly implement the transfer?
(the number of cells is generated automatically)

Another complication is that the code of the cell with which I work lies in another cell.

those. the transfer of information must also be written in it.

```
import UIKit
import moa

class RealPhotoInfoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var MyCollection: UICollectionView!

    var model: RealPhoto!

    func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: UICollectionViewDataSource & UICollectionViewDelegate, forRow row: Int) {
        MyCollection.delegate = self
        MyCollection.dataSource = self
        MyCollection.reloadData()
    }
}

extension RealPhotoInfoTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(model?.data.count as Any)
        return model?.data.count ?? 0
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RPhotoCell", for: indexPath) as! RealPhotoCollectionViewCell

        cell.realPhotoImage.moa.url = model?.data[indexPath.row].photo

        return cell
    } 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

Add a var

```
class RealPhotoInfoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   weak var delegate:VCName?
```

Inside `cellForRowAt` of the table do

```
cell.delegate = self
```

Now you can do this inside `didSelectItemAt` of the collection

```
delegate?.sendData(image)
```

Comment: thanks, I tried to do as you describe
But it does not come out.

I will update the question, please take a look.

Comment: @Сева `cell.delegate = self` should be inside the tableView `cellForRowAt` not the collection

Comment: it still doesn't work.

in the first VC where I have a tableview, I have prescribed 
`realPfotoCell.delegate = self`

and have an error 
`Cannot assign value of type 'DetailViewController' to type 'ImagesViewController?'`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:
One is Sh_Khan answer using delegation.

Or you can use Notification observers.

This question has been asked before...

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate protocol in that case. You can implement that protocol. Please find following sample code for that.

```
protocol ImageSelectionDelegate {
    func imageClicked(imageURL: String)
}

//Class A
class A : ImageSelectionDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //your existing code
        cell.delegate = self
    }
    //Implement that protocol
    func imageClicked(imageURL: String){
        //You will get url for tapped image
    }
}

class RealPhotoInfoTableViewCell{
    weak var delegate : ImageSelectionDelegate? = nil
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate.imageClicked(model?.data[indexPath.item].photo)
    }
}
```